# Symmetric key importance During encrypt and decrypt

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes, decryption, tpm

I am performing a small command line operation the goal is to generate a symmetric key using openssl and store the key in TPM FAPI keystore.

After modifying the symmetric key, the decryption should fail, but it decrypts successfully.

What am I doing wrong? This is what I have tried so far.

```
openssl rand 128 > symmetric_keyfile.key
echo "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy" > sec.txt
openssl enc -in sec.txt -out secrets.txt.enc -e -aes256 -k symmetric_keyfile.key
echo "adding random characters literally modifying the symmetric key" >> symmetric_keyfile.key
openssl enc -in secrets.txt.enc -out secrets.txt.decrypted -d -aes256 -k symmetric_keyfile.key
cat secrets.txt.decrypted 
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

Comment: I don't think the `-k` option does what you think it does.  See https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html.

Comment: It seems you're using the string `symmetric_keyfile.key` as the password instead of using the contents of the file. The password you've generated is also 128 bytes long, not 128 bits long (which is 16 bytes). If you want AES-256, your key needs to be 256 bits (32 bytes) long. I think `openssl enc` is not a direct AES API, it uses PBKDF2 and stuff. I would not use openssl CLI, just use python with pyca/cryptography package which uses openssl (libcrypto) under the hood but with a sane API. Or a different wrapper with a sane API.

Comment: @Z.T.: `openssl enc` by default uses its own PBKDF, `EVP_BytesToKey`, but in 1.1.1 up can _optionally_ use PBKDF2, and in all versions can optionally use a direct key specified _with uppercase `-K` in hex_ (and when applicable the IV with `-iv` also in hex)

Comment: @Z.T.@mti2935  I am accepting the comment , I have modified the -k argument a.k.a password, the decrypt fails, but how to read from file `symmetric_keyfile.key` I need to figure it out, I will be developing a key using openssl libs using C code and call FAPI apis to store the key.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was user error with the wrong command argument